# Scientific Linux 7.2 stops displaying X locally

Tags: linux, redhat, scientific-linux, xorg

I'm having the weirdest issue. We use SL7.2 and have a network home directory and AD + SSSD for auth. This means I can go to different computers and get a consistent home dir as well as UID/GID etc. I have a physical KVM to set up computers more easily.

I started having an issue where my workstation would stop displaying X to my monitor. The monitor will say "No Signal" It would work fine until I switched away via the KVM to another computer, when I switched back X would not display. I could connect via Bomgar and see my X session, it was fine. I could ctrl-alt-F3 and the virtual terminal would display, but the only way to get X back was to reboot.

I thought it might be the KVM, so I connected the monitor via DVI directly to the workstation. No change.

I thought it was an issue with the hardware or the OS install, so I set up a brand new Lenovo P510 with a new SL7.2 install. Now it will loose X if I just don't use it for a while (I think it's the screen locking?).

I thought it might be the monitor - maybe it's old and loosing signal, or the new Display port to DVI adapter can be funky, so I installed a brand new BENQ GW2765, connected directly via Display Port to the nVidia card (this card only has Display Port connectors - 4x). No change.

So now I'm thinking - it HAS to be software, and it has to be something in my configuration. But I don't really even know where to start looking - /var/log/messages and /var/log/Xorg.0.log don't show anything that's obvious to me.

How can I fix X not coming back?

EDIT: I have confirmed that it only happens when I turn off the monitor. I left my new monitor on overnight - and X did not die. The problem with this is SL7.2 never actually turns off the monitor's backlight so I think it's bad for the monitors longevity.

Comment: Sounds like you narrowed the problem and have your answer.  You should list the answer and mark it answered, so that folks can refer to this and know whether it applies in their situation.

Comment: Well, no - X shouldn't die when you turn off your monitor.